# merge on column based relational table in gridview yii2

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

in index.php :

```
'columns' => [
     ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
       'ID_REQUEST',
       'NOMOR_SURAT',
       [
          'label' => 'Nama Depan',    
          'attribute' => 'ID_KARYAWAN',
          'value' => 'iDKARYAWAN.FIRST_NAME'
       ],
       [
          'label' => 'Nama Belakang',
          'attribute' => 'ID_KARYAWAN',
          'value' => 'iDKARYAWAN.LAST_NAME'
       ],
```

which is iDKARYAWAN is relation from another table in my model

```
class Request extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName() {
    return 'ytms_it.request';
}

 public function getIDKARYAWAN() {
    return $this->hasOne(Karyawan::className(), ['ID_KARYAWAN' => 'ID_KARYAWAN'])->from(Karyawan::tableName(). ' b');
}
```

How to merge those two column  ?

For the elp, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create method called `getFullName()` in related model and calculate full name using PHP concatenation:

```
use yii\helpers\Html;

...

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getFullName()
{
    return Html::encode($this->name . ' ' . $this->surname);
}
```

Optionally define a label for it in `attributeLabels()` method of related model:

```
`fullName` => 'Label for full name',
```

Then in GridView it's possible to display full name of related model in one column like so:

**1)** The shortest form:

```
'relatedModel.fullName',
```

**2)** Overriding the label:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'relatedModel.fullName',
    'label' => 'Overrided label',
],
```

**3)** Using closure:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'relatedModel.fullName', // The attribute name can be different in this case
    'value' => function ($model) {
        // You can calculate full name here.
        // But it's better to just call according method since view is only for display.
        return $model->author->fullName; 
    },
],
```

Another way is to calculate full name using SQL and include as a part of query result in separate column.

Use [Active Record - Selecting extra fields](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#selecting-extra-fields) official docs section as a guide, also see this related issue on Github - [JoinWith - assign a column aliases to an attribute of related model](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/12846).

Add `$fullName` as public property of related model class. Modify query like so:

```
use yii\db\Expression;

...

->joinWith(['relatedModel' => function (\yii\db\ActiveQuery $query) {
    $query->addSelect('fullName' => new Expression("CONCAT(name, ' ', surname)")]);
}]
```

Then to display it in `GridView` column you can use one of the options desribed above, for example:

```
'relatedModel.fullName'
```